# A Town of Horror

Tags: riddle, knowledge, wordplay

There was a town, full of people. 
But that town was not very simple.

Only 15 people, and they march outside. 
Day goes and night comes, and they go inside.

Each day you vote, and you go on trial. 
If you are wrong, you get hanged, which ends your survival. 
If you are virtuous to others, you show another arrival.

Each person has a different character. 
Some are good, some are evil, some are neither.

You don't know who the good is, neither you know the evil. 
If you are the evil, you know who the evils are.

Some goods, knows information about the evil. 
Some kills the evil. 
Some delays the evil. 
Some protects the evil.

The good slowly dies at night, and tries to hang the evil. 
The evil kills the good each night, and acts like a good.

Every supernatural beings can be seen till this day. 
Except zombies, who really don't die as they say.

Some are there who does not like to die. 
Some are there who likes himself to die. 
Some are there who likes someone else to die. 
Some are there who wants both, good and evil, to die.

In the end, you win this whole town. 
The deads watch as they see. 
That the good old folks killed the evils. 
And the town will be empty as it is to be.

I am talking about a game which fits all these clues, can you guess what it is? 
 (Explanations needed)

I will provide hints as time goes.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be much of a riddle to me - it's more "here's a description of a thing; identify the thing". Riddles are typically meant to have *some* form of obfuscation or wordplay, that hides the identity of the object, but becomes obvious afterwards. (Something like "oh, *mouth* meant the mouth of a river, and not an animal's mouth!") The only thing stopping someone from answering this is familiarity with the source, not any actual 'tricks'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This just appears to be a direct description of

> the game [Town of Salem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Town_of_Salem), a 15-player social deduction game in the same vein as Mafia/Werewolf. Players are randomly given "good" or "evil" roles, and the good players (who have the majority) have to try to figure out the evil players (who know who is on their team) before the evil players can kill them off.
>
>  The text is straightforward enough that there is nothing to explain for most of them beyond "yes, that is a description of this game". A few of the paragraphs in the middle describe some of the roles: for instance, the Jester, a neutral player who wants to be voted out, and the Executioner, who wants a certain other person to be voted out. Other than that, though, there's not much to explain, because the text says exactly what it means.

Comment: It does sound like Among Us, but with a twist.

Comment: @zixuan Yes, Among Us is a similar social deduction game. There are many others in the genre, including the board games One Night Ultimate Werewolf, The Resistance, and Bang!, and the video game Push The Button (from the Jackbox Party Pack 6).